# python filter lines matching keyworks

Tags: python, regex, linux, scripting

I have working python script producing following output.

```
import re
import sys
import socket
conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
conn.connect(('10.10.10.10', 25001))
conn.send('status\n')
data = conn.recv(16777216)
conn.close()
print data
```

Script output

```
session 3594154272 xwf9VgJQfRSSPBCyXYVRzlw==foo xh_iUVQ6JRieFv70JjDVOnQ==bar 13584
stream 102.22.133.12:33562 173.24.54.19:39814 10.10.10.10:12838 39382628/29008576/68391204 
session 3363219694 xiXdeg8oGTQ6MYZ-Z5q4iKw==foo xVBsa0nlZT4-vOLA8P-WxSw==bar 2319
stream 71.22.223.192:43718 115.125.65.61:41126 10.10.10.10:12802 4243204/9624660/13867864
....
....
....
```

Now i want want any line starting with `stream` in output so i am using following logic but its not working.

```
import re
import sys
import socket
conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
conn.connect(('10.10.10.10', 25001))
conn.send('status\n')
data = conn.recv(16777216)
conn.close()

# parse line contain stream
for line in data:
    if re.match(r'stream', line):
        print line,
```

Comment: Why not `if line.startswith('stream '):`

Comment: you mean `if line.startswith('stream ', line):` ? i am new to python so if you give little details would be good, anyway i have tried `if line.startswith('stream '):` but seeing blank output.

Comment: Just `if line.startswith('stream '): print line` is what @anubhava was referring to.  It's a [`string` method.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) (I'm assuming this is python 2.7 from the looks of it.)

Comment: I have replaced `if re.match(r'stream', line):` with `if line.startswith('stream '):` and script output is blank, do you think my string isn't matching?

Comment: `python mp.py | wc -l` and result is `12968` lines, every single character is new line...

Comment: Your `data` is a `string`, not a `list` of `strings` then.  Use `for line in data.split('\n'):`

Comment: @Idlehands - awesome!!!! it works great, last question how do i count lines in python? i don't want to open new question for simple function ;)

Comment: `for n, line in enumerate(data.split('\n')):`, where `n` is the incremental number of *total* lines (not just the matched ones).  If you want to count only the matched lines, do a `count = 0` before the loop and `count += 1` in each `if` block.

Comment: Great!! it works.. Please post answer so i can vote answer. Thanks to  @anubhava for hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` is a massive `string` instead of a `list` of `strings` as you expected.  Also it's easier to use [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) instead of regex (less resource hungry).  Simply change your code as follows:

```
# parse line contain stream
for n, line in enumerate(data.split('\n')):
    if line.startswith('stream '):
        print line
```

Where `n` is the *total* number of lines you have in your `data`.  If you only wanted to count the specific times you encountered `"stream"`:

```
count = 0
for line in data.split('\n'):
    if line.startswith('stream '):
        print line
        count += 1
```